# System.Diagnostics.Process from ManagementBaseObject

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, wmi

I'm executing a remote process using WMI and would like to redirect the StandardOutput of that process back to my program. I have found these code examples:

http://haripotter.wordpress.com/2008/07/25/executing-a-command-on-a-remote-windows-system-using-wmi/

That person is using the Process class which I see here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ssk42c11.aspx

Can redirect standard output. Is it possible to use these two together?

I am invoking it this way:

```
 public string StartProcess(string command)
    {
        ManagementClass processTask = new ManagementClass(@"\\" + this.wmiConnection.machineName + @"\root\CIMV2", "Win32_Process", null);
        ManagementBaseObject methodParams = processTask.GetMethodParameters("Create");
        methodParams["CommandLine"] = command;
        methodParams["CurrentDirectory"] = @"C:\";


        try
        {
            ManagementBaseObject exitCode = processTask.InvokeMethod("Create", methodParams, null);
```

Comment: Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/

Answer (score 0):

I think you're a little confused about this. There is not posible mix the [`Win32_Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WMI class (or any) and the [`System.Diagnostics.Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) class, both belong to different scopes. About your another questions, I think you are out luck here, because with the `System.Diagnostics.Process` class you cna redirect the standard output but does not allow execute a remote process, and wiht the `Win32_Process` WMI Class you can execute a remote process (with limitations) but does not allow redirect the standard  output.

Comment: So is there no way I can get the output of a remote process to come back to my program?

Comment: Sure you can do this, but you need build  Client-Server App your self to send commands to the remote machine (Server) and receive the output in the client side.

Comment: The $0.02 solution is redirecting output to a file with cmd.exe, then read the file after the process completes.

Comment: @Hans yeah you can do  that, but how you can get the content of the file which is located in the server machine?

Comment: A boomerang that doesn't come back is a stick.  A server that you can't get files off is a brick ;)

Comment: Indeed! Unfortuantly i cannot deploy an agent to the remote machine (its against my design requirement). Right now I'm pipping the output to a file, mapping the drive by issuing a net use command and copying it to local. DISGUSTING! Especially with the slowness of drive mounting over windows (For which I am literally doing:Thread.Sleep(3000) gross!) 

I'm really trying to find a way to get that boomerang to come back to me :)

Comment: Also using psexec is against my design requirements as is using power shell (PSexec is often associated with malicious users and power shell is not enabled on windows xp machines by default so I would not be able use it on all the machines I am interested in)